# Opening Multiple MDL Modal Dialogues?

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, material-design-lite

I have this idea that I would like a product page on my website which has two MDL cards which both have MDL pop-up dialogues when a button is clicked. Both of these pop-ups will show different product options.

I have built the cards and buttons, but only one of them appears to work, is there a way to launch two dialogues on the same page? Javascript is not my strong point but what I have works for one of the dialogues.

Also, whilst letting my imagination run crazy, I've not thought about the possibility that I may not be able to contain a 'Quick Look' product within my pop-up dialogue, I see this done on many websites but not sure if I am actually able to do this within the dialogue.

HTML

```
 <div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
              <div class="mdl-card__title">
                <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text"></h2>
              </div>
              <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sagittis pellentesque lacus eleifend lacinia...
              </div>
              <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
                  <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-button dialog-button">Show Dialog</button>

                  <dialog id="dialog" class="mdl-dialog">
                      <h3 class="mdl-dialog__title">MDL Dialog</h3>
                      <div class="mdl-dialog__content">
                        <p>
                          This is an example of the Material Design Lite dialog component.
                          Please use responsibly.
                        </p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
                        <button type="button" class="mdl-button">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="mdl-button" disabled>Disabled action</button>
                      </div>
                    </dialog>
           </div>

              <div class="mdl-card__menu">
                <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
      <i class="material-icons">share</i>
    </button>
              </div>
            </div>
```

JS:

```
 (function() {
    'use strict';
    var dialogButton = document.querySelector('.dialog-button');
    var dialog = document.querySelector('#dialog');
    if (! dialog.showModal) {
      dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
    }
    dialogButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
       dialog.showModal();
    });
    dialog.querySelector('button:not([disabled])')
    .addEventListener('click', function() {
      dialog.close();
    });
  }());
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a second dialog (in this case dialog-1, dialog-button-1)

```
        <div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
          <div class="mdl-card__title">
            <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text"></h2>
          </div>
          <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sagittis pellentesque lacus eleifend lacinia...
          </div>
          <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
              <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-button dialog-button-1">View Product</button>

              <dialog id="dialog-1" class="mdl-dialog">
                  <h3 class="mdl-dialog__title">Product 2</h3>
                  <div class="mdl-dialog__content">
                    <p>
                      This is an example of the Material Design Lite dialog component.
                      Please use responsibly.
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
                    <button type="button" class="mdl-button">Close</button>

                  </div>
                </dialog>

          </div>
          <div class="mdl-card__menu">
            <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
  <i class="material-icons">share</i>
</button>
          </div>
```

Double up on Javascript

```
   (function() {
    'use strict';
    var dialogButton = document.querySelector('.dialog-button-1');
    var dialog = document.querySelector('#dialog-1');
    if (! dialog.showModal) {
      dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
    }
    dialogButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
       dialog.showModal();
    });
    dialog.querySelector('button:not([disabled])')
    .addEventListener('click', function() {
      dialog.close();
    });
  }());
```

Yet to see how this works using it as a product quick-look, but so far it works well, however, I have noticed issues with it not functioning on Safari.